# JAX-RS client to send/receive messages in POJO objects

Tags: json, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have the following codes that work. It sends a JSON request to a JAX-RS web service with POST method, and receives back a JSON response. Both the JSON request and response are in String objects. However, I would like them to be encapsulated in POJO objects instead, such that I send a POJO object and the response will be in POJO object. How do I do so?

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
WebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromUri("http://.....").build());
Invocation.Builder builder = target.path("Test").request();
builder = builder.accept(MediaType.WILDCARD);
String jsonRequest = "{ "staffID":"123456", "token":"010101" }";
Response response = builder.post(Entity.json(jsonRequest));
String jsonResponse = response.readEntity(String.class);
System.out.println(jsonResponse);
```

Comment: I downloaded all the Jackson JAR files. Then I changed my codes to the following and it works: POJO pojo = new POJO();
pojo.setStaffID("A111111");
...
response = builder.post(Entity.entity(pojo, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
POJO responsePOJO = response.readEntity(POJO.class);

Comment: In my JAX-RS web service, which runs on Weblogic 12.2.1, I don't need Jackson. But it is able to convert POJO to and from JSON. Here is signature: public Response getNotifications(@Context HttpServletRequest request, POJO requestBody); How come the web service works without Jackson bundled in the war file?

Comment: Yes, peeskillet. The client codes works now. Just including the Jackson JAR files and changing the codes to above makes it work. Now I am curious to know why my web service does not require Jackson but still can convert POJO to/from JSON.

Comment: Weblogic already has a JSON provider, but 1) that is for the server 2) if you are using the client on the server it's because WebLogic uses Jersey 1.x by default. It doesn't recongnize JAX-RS 2.x client, and won't register the provider with the client. If you were to use the Jersey 1.x client, I would imagine that you wouldn't need to register any provider, and it would just use the one provider by the server jars

Comment: I may be wrong, I don't use WebLogic, but from what I remember from other other posts, Jersey 1.x is the JAX-RS 1.1. implementation in WebLogic. It does not use JAX-RS 2.0

Comment: In WebLogic 12.2.1, I have deployed jax-rs(2.0,2.21.1.0) before my web service war file was deployed. This is a jar file that comes with WebLogic. This means that it should be using JAX-RS 2.0. I used my latest codes in a web service, and I experimented without adding the Jackson jar files to the war file. It was able to marshall the JSON request to POJO, and the opposite as well. That means the provider is already register in WebLogic. I only need the Jackson jar files if my codes is in a client program.